# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index' when finding index of a value in an array

Tags: python

I'm trying to find an index of an element in my array called svmoutput. The freq[0] is alway 1. by enumerating the svmoutput, I want to find the index of all the ones and and find the related value in cluster0Data array. I want to iterate over svmoutput and find 1 then find its index and then find the related element having that index in cluster0Data. Again I continue iterating over svmoutput and then find the next 1 in it and then should find its index and find the related element having that index in cluster0Data Here is what I tried till now, but it shows me error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

```
  for t in svmoutput:
        if svmoutput[t] == freq[0]:
           numbers = np.array(svmoutput)
           ultimate.append(cluster0Data[numbers.index(svmoutput[t])])
```

Here is svmoutput=[-1 1 1 -1]

I appreciate if anyone can suggest me how can I solve it.

Comment: because `numpy.ndarray` objects don't have that method. Why don't you just sue a `list`?

Comment: I tried to use a list without converting it to NumPy but it showed me the same error

Comment: It does not. `list` objects have an `index` attribute. So if you did `numbers = list(svmoutput)` it should work. If it doesn't, you really must provide a [mcve]

Comment: As `svmoutput==numbers`. `svmoutput.index(svmoutput[t])` will just yield `t`

Comment: when I write svmoutput.index(svmoutput[t]) it shows me the following error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: For simplicity be sure that all your lists are actual python lists or all are numpy arrays, as they are not 100% interchangeable and compatible in both directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index works for normal python lists.

numpy arrays don't have that methods

```
np.where(numbers == vmoutput[t])[0]
```

is one solution.
`numbers == vmoutput[t]` will create a boolean array `[False, False, True, True]` where the condition matches. [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) will filter the indices *where* they are True and return a tuple where the first element[0] are the indices you are looking for.
Note that these can be more than one index depending on the setting.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It shows me the error: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: Here is what I wrote: ultimate.append(cluster0Data[ np.where(numbers == svmoutput[t])[0]])

Comment: That should be the case if cluster0Data is a normal list. Here it depends do you expect exactly one index to match? Then you can use np.where(numbers == svmoutput[t])[0][0] if you expect more to match, declare cluster0Data = np.array(cluster0Data) somewhere above the code.

Comment: I want to iterate over svmoutput and find 1 then find its index and then find the related element having that index in cluster0Data. Again I iterate in svmoutput and then find the next 1 in it and then should find its index and find the related element having that index in cluster0Data ....

Comment: the method you mentioned  np.where(numbers == svmoutput[t])[0][0]  just prints out the index of the first occurrence of one. I need after it found the first occurrence index then by iterating over svmoutput array finding the second occurrence of one and match it with cluster0 to find the element that has the same index and ...

Comment: As said that is only valid if you want exactly one index. If there are more remove the last [0] and np.where will give you the indices of all positions.